# how to use linked animated css?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am trying to use animate.css

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="animate.css" type='text/css'>
```

which is this:

```
.animated {
    -webkit-animation-duration: 2s;
    -moz-animation-duration: 2s;
    -o-animation-duration: 2s;
    animation-duration: 2s;
    -webkit-animation-fill-mode: both;
    -moz-animation-fill-mode: both;
    -o-animation-fill-mode: both;
    animation-fill-mode: both;
}
@-webkit-keyframes wobble {
    0% {
        -webkit-transform: translateX(0%);
    }
    15% {
        -webkit-transform: translateX(-25%) rotate(-5deg);
    }
    30% {
        -webkit-transform: translateX(20%) rotate(3deg);
    }
    45% {
        -webkit-transform: translateX(-15%) rotate(-3deg);
    }
    60% {
        -webkit-transform: translateX(10%) rotate(2deg);
    }
    75% {
        -webkit-transform: translateX(-5%) rotate(-1deg);
    }
    100% {
        -webkit-transform: translateX(0%);
    }
}
@-moz-keyframes wobble {
    0% {
        -moz-transform: translateX(0%);
    }
    15% {
        -moz-transform: translateX(-25%) rotate(-5deg);
    }
    30% {
        -moz-transform: translateX(20%) rotate(3deg);
    }
    45% {
        -moz-transform: translateX(-15%) rotate(-3deg);
    }
    60% {
        -moz-transform: translateX(10%) rotate(2deg);
    }
    75% {
        -moz-transform: translateX(-5%) rotate(-1deg);
    }
    100% {
        -moz-transform: translateX(0%);
    }
}
@-o-keyframes wobble {
    0% {
        -o-transform: translateX(0%);
    }
    15% {
        -o-transform: translateX(-25%) rotate(-5deg);
    }
    30% {
        -o-transform: translateX(20%) rotate(3deg);
    }
    45% {
        -o-transform: translateX(-15%) rotate(-3deg);
    }
    60% {
        -o-transform: translateX(10%) rotate(2deg);
    }
    75% {
        -o-transform: translateX(-5%) rotate(-1deg);
    }
    100% {
        -o-transform: translateX(0%);
    }
}
@keyframes wobble {
    0% {
        transform: translateX(0%);
    }
    15% {
        transform: translateX(-25%) rotate(-5deg);
    }
    30% {
        transform: translateX(20%) rotate(3deg);
    }
    45% {
        transform: translateX(-15%) rotate(-3deg);
    }
    60% {
        transform: translateX(10%) rotate(2deg);
    }
    75% {
        transform: translateX(-5%) rotate(-1deg);
    }
    100% {
        transform: translateX(0%);
    }
}
.animated.wobble {
    -webkit-animation-name: wobble;
    -moz-animation-name: wobble;
    -o-animation-name: wobble;
    animation-name: wobble;
}
```

And HTML:

```
<a class="yo">yo</a>
```

And then Jquery:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

$(document).ready(function(){ 
$(".yo").click(function() {
         $(this).addClass('animated wobble');
});
});
```

But when I click on `yo` it changes the classes (so I know the jquery is working) but nothing happens. I have also added a class to the css and changed the font colour and it works (so I know that the link is working properly) But still no wobble animation when I click?

Comment: Are you sure the stylesheet is being loaded?

Comment: yes 100% sure! I have tried it in this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/X4pr7/1/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you need specify which animation gets called. Try adding this to your animated class:

```
.animated {
   -webkit-animation-name: wobble;
   -moz-animation-name: wobble;
   -o-animation-name: wobble;
   animation-name: wobble;
}
```

Wobble isn't a classname, it's just the name of your animation, so you can remove the wobble addClass in your jQuery.

**EDIT:** Looks like I didn't read all your CSS. Try moving your 
`.animated.wobble{}` section right up underneath the `.animated{}` section.

Comment: But he defines that `animation-name ` in his CSS for the elements with a class of both `animated` and `wobble` (both of which are added with jQuery).

Comment: @DavidThomas: Oh, my bad. I must have not scrolled down far enough in the css. Rookie mistake, I guess. :S